# SwiftUI Binding property inside of view model

Tags: ios, swiftui

I'm having an issue with a Binding property inside of a view model that's being created in another view model. Here is simplified version of 2 views:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel = ContentViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            // binding through `@Published var toggleViewModel`
            ToggleWrapperView(viewModel: viewModel.toggleViewModel)
            
            // binding through `var isOnBinding: Binding<Bool>`
            ToggleWrapperView(viewModel: ToggleViewModel(isOn: viewModel.isOnBinding!, title: "Binding through isOnBinding"))
            
            // binding through `@Published var isOn`
            ToggleWrapperView(viewModel: ToggleViewModel(isOn: $viewModel.isOn, title: "Binding through view"))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct ToggleWrapperView: View {
    var viewModel: ToggleViewModel
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Toggle(isOn: viewModel.$isOn, label: {
                Text(viewModel.title + " \(viewModel.isOn)")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

And here are view models for the views:

```
class ContentViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @ObservedObject var dataManager = DataManager()
    @Published var toggleViewModel: ToggleViewModel!
    
    @Published var isOn: Bool = false // Property for the binding in the ContentView

    private var privateIsOnForBinding: Bool = false
    var isOnBinding: Binding<Bool>?
    
    init() {
        toggleViewModel = ToggleViewModel(isOn: $dataManager.isOn, title: "Binding from DataManager")
        initBinding()
    }
    
    func initBinding() {
        isOnBinding = Binding {
            self.privateIsOnForBinding
        } set: { updatedValue in
            self.privateIsOnForBinding = updatedValue
            print(self.isOnBinding!)
        }
    }
}

struct ToggleViewModel {
    @Binding var isOn: Bool
    let title: String
}

class DataManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var isOn: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            print("did set DataManager.isOn \(isOn)")
        }
    }
}
```

From the `ToggleWrapperView` examples above only binding created with `$viewModel.isOn` is working as expected on toggle action.

In the example with `toggleViewModel` I can see that the property in `DataManager` is being updated (print in the property observer), but the binding itself stays `false`

```
Binding<Bool>(transaction: SwiftUI.Transaction(plist: []), location: SwiftUI.LocationBox<SwiftUI.(unknown context at $1c5c1c4dc).ObjectLocation<BindingTest.DataManager, Swift.Bool>>, _value: false)
```

And using `var isOnBinding: Binding<Bool>` gives me the same result, binding is not being updated

```
Binding<Bool>(transaction: SwiftUI.Transaction(plist: []), location: SwiftUI.LocationBox<SwiftUI.FunctionalLocation<Swift.Bool>>, _value: false)
```

This is just a simplified example, but I'd like to understand why 2 versions don't work.
I can make the example with `toggleViewModel` to work if I mark `var viewModel: ToggleViewModel` as `@Binding` in the `ToggleWrapperView`, and remove the `@Binding` from the `isOn` property of `ToggleViewModel` (first example in the view).
However I'm trying to have the binding for the `isOn` between `ToggleViewModel` and `DataManager` if possible.

Comment: `@Binding` and `@ObservedObject` are only meaningful in a `View`, not in classes or structs.
 Note I would advice against **nesting** `ObservableObject`.
Look at this link for how to manage data in your app:  [Monitoring data](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/monitoring-model-data-changes-in-your-app)

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI the `View` struct is the view model already so you can just remove the `class ContentViewModel` it's going to cause you lots of consistency and performance issues if you keep trying to do make that work. Your aim should be to get all of your data into the `View` struct hierarchy, that way the UI will update consistently.

Use:

```
@State var isOn: Bool = false
```

For your source of truth and supply it to child Views as a let for readonly or `@Binding var` for read/write. Regardless `body` will be called when the value changes, think of `body` like an onChanged for every `let`, `@State var`, `@Binding var` declared in the `View`.

If you want to group related vars or have testable logic you can use a @State struct, e.g.

```
struct Content {

    var isOn1: Bool = false
    var isOn2: Bool = false {
        didSet {

         }
    }

   mutating func reset() {
        isOn1 = false
        isOn1 = false
    }
}
...

@State var content = Content()
...
Toggle(isOn: $content.isOn)
```

Finally use computed vars to transform your readonly data into the child View's init. That way when the source of truth changes, SwiftUI will call body which in turn calls your computed property and everything will be correct. You would lose all of this consistency if you put data in your own class.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I understand that using `@State` is the correct way for the example above. In real example I have multiple text editors, toggles and other views to show, so I have multiple smaller reusable views that could be configured with different color, font, etc. `DataManager` is specific to this view type that would fetch remote data and use some data from Core Data and format it. In the view model I'm trying to allow to configure the view components (font, color, etc.) and have binding between editable property of the view (text, isOn, etc) to the data in `DataManager`

Comment: Use multiple `View` structs and use `ViewModifier` for reusable color/font styling. That's just how SwiftUI is designed to work I'm afraid. You can use a `@StateObject` for a data fetcher/loader but not for view data.